# How could this be true $n=\log(e^n)$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, elementary-functions

I am learning elementary logarithms.

> How could this be true $n=\log(e^n)$?

I searched online and couldn't find any info on this, could anyone give me some clue?

Comment: $\log_a x=y\iff a^y=x$.

Comment: Hint: What is $\log$?

Comment: [Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html) is what you want.

Comment: log(a^b)=b*log(a). and logarithm of any number to the same base is 1.

Comment: @GrandAlpha blog?

Comment: @ADG exactly "blog".  He means to say $\log (a^b) = b\cdot \log(a)$ by properties of logarithms and exponents.

Answer (score 8):

The confusion might be that here $\log$ denotes the logarithm to base $e$ the Euler constant. So it is the natural logarithm, often also denoted $\ln$.

Then that $n = \log (e^n)$ is true is just the definition of the logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

For any real $n\geq 0$, we have 
$$ n=\log_e\left(e^n\right) $$
$$ n=n\log_e\left(e\right) $$
$$ n=n\cdot 1$$
$$ n=n$$

Answer (score 0):

The two function $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\ln x$ are inverse of each other, so their composition is the identity function: $$gof(x)=\ln(e^x)=x$$